# Distinguish Services from different nodes with same name

Tags: ros, rosnode, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I wish to create 2 rosnodes with some services having same name. E.g. rosnode **N1 has services S1,S2,S4** and rosnode **N2 has services S2,S3,S5**. The reason to have services of same name is because they for a part of a generic description.
However, I am not able to find a solution which can help me call the service from a specific node like **N1.S2 and N2.S2**.
I am using python as my programming environment.

Also is it possible to get the proxy object of one node into another ?Like
**proxyForN1 = someRosCode.getProxyForNode('N1')**
The call the service of that node from the proxy like **proxyForN1 .callService('S2')** ?

It would be great if anyone could help out here !!
Cheers !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270628/distinguish-services-from-different-nodes-with-same-name/) by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you make sure to make the services of those nodes *private* (ie: `advertise(..)` them on a private nodehandle, or prefix the service name with the node name), then you just need to prefix the nodename to the service name when you create the service proxy as well.

Alternatively, you could start nodes in namespaces, which will automatically prefix service names (provided the service names haven't been made global (ie: start with a `/`).

---

Edit:

> Hi, Thanks for the response :)
> Are you suggesting something like to start the server:

> ```
> s = rospy.Service(' serviceRequest = rospy.ServiceProxy('NodeName/ServiceName', NodeName_ServiceName, callback_function)
> ```

No. That doesn't make sense to me.

Note: there is nothing magical about service names, they are just strings that we use as an address or URI.

To advertise a service in `rospy` that is *private* to `n0`, do something like (from the *Writing a Simple Service and Client* tutorial):

```
s = rospy.Service('~/add_two_ints', AddTwoInts, handle_add_two_ints)
```

This should result in a `/n0/add_two_ints` service server. Note the `~`. We could use the node name, but if a user of your node specifies a different name (fi in their launch file), your service won't be properly prefixed.

In your service client you'd have to know that the service server is named `n0`, and you can then do (again from the tutorial):

```
add_two_ints = rospy.ServiceProxy('/n0/add_two_ints', AddTwoInts)
```

If you don't want start private services, you could also use [namespacing](http://wiki.ros.org/Names), but that will require your client to be in the same namespace as your server, *or* you need to provide your client with the required information (ie: the namespace).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-11**:
Hi, Thanks for the response :)
Are you suggesting something like:-
to start the server :- **s = rospy.Service(' serviceRequest = rospy.ServiceProxy('NodeName/ServiceName', NodeName_ServiceName, callback_function)**  ??

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-11**:
If not, could you please give a small example ?? :)
Cheers !!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-11**:
Note btw that hard-coding node names like this is not very flexible and will most likely make re-use of your nodes outside this narrow use-case more difficult than it could/should be.

**Comment by [amarbanerjee23](https://answers.ros.org/users/30844/amarbanerjee23/) on 2017-09-12**:
Hi @gvdhoorn,
The suggested solution works completely fine. I see your point you said above, but for now my problem will be solved !!
Thanks a lot man !! Cheers !!